# Closed-source licence that limits liability and warranty

Tags: copyright, software, licensing, liability

Is there any software licence that I can freely grab that only limits my liability while not additionally allowing any distribution and have other open-source permissions? Since what I understand is that my software is copyrighted to me unless stated otherwise, and the only part I really NEED in my lincense is to protect myself. So since I would rather not spend my time figuring out how to put together legally binding lincense or spend a lot of money on lawyer for a pet project of mine (that I want to try to profit from). Since it seems to be relevant, I'm from Europe (Poland).

Would something like part taken from unlicense.org be suitable?

> THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND,
>   EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF
>   MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT.
>   IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR
>   OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE,
>   ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR
>   OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.

Comment: This is a specific legal question, and we can't answer such questions.  We can give general guidance, but this goes beyond it.  For this answer, you need to consult with a lawyer in your jurisdiction.  There may be a way to have a short inexpensive consultation (in the US, I'd suggest asking your local bar association).

Comment: That's not a license, it's simply a claim. Claiming something doesn't make that thing true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't answer that question here.  We can make some observations.

First, the Unlicense is applied to software that's basically free for anyone to do anything with. It's basically making the software available, not warranting it for any particular purpose.  If you sell software, it's presumably for a purpose, so there will likely be some sort of legal warranty or liability that can't be disclaimed in the license.  This depends on where you are, which you don't tell us.

Second, if you're planning to make money, consulting a lawyer is a worthwhile investment.  Paying to get a license that does what you want is likely to be far less expensive than using a license that leaves you open to problems.  Think of it as a business expense.

Comment: Ok thanks for adivce, but while I do want to try to make money, I don't expect to make that much since its my first time trying to do something like that, I feel it might not be enough to offset lawyer costs (Maybe I need to change business model).
I will look into local lawyers though, thanks.